# how to mock providers specified in @component meta data in angular-2.0.0-rc-4

Tags: javascript, angular

since, overrideProviders is not supported in angular-2.0.0-rc-4.

i tried using

```
beforeEach(() => {
addProviders([
    TestComponentBuilder,
    FeedsListComponent, {
        provide: FeedsService,
        useClass: MockFeedsService
    }
]);
```

});

i am able to mock the service if it was provided at bootstrap phase.
but if it's provided @componet level like below

```
@component({
 ...
 providers: ['FeedsService']
})
class FeedsListComponent {
}
```

even if i used provide it's not taking the mockedService. So, is there any alternative way to mock the services specified in @component meta data instead of overrideProviders

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `overrideProviders` from `TestComponentBuilder`

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/testing/TestComponentBuilder-class.html

Comment: i tried overrideproviders to test with rc-4 , but it is depericated. it would be great if you can give sample example plunker or code snippet.

Comment: There are lots of examples in the Angular GitHub repo https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9af2d8b8106f9dd128edfe9c582644a6f6303300/modules/%40angular/core/test/linker/view_injector_integration_spec.ts#L308 I wouldn't worry for now about the deprecation. There are bigger changes to be expected again for RC.5 then they will hopefully provide more details how to migrate.

Comment: currently i am planning to use rc4 in my new project,these are the blockers i am seeing .. any idea rc 5 release date?

Comment: I just saw that there were several commits recently about the test API with back and forth about what will be deprecated and replaced by what. I think we need to wait for the changelog and the updated docs.